# Foundation sass override property for an element with ID

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

How do I override properties for an element with a specific ID using Foundation and Sass?

I have a `<section id='myid'>` and want to override some properties for this:

```
#myid {
   background: blue;
   color: white;
}
```

If I put this in a CSS file, or in the app.scss file it won't be applied. It is in the compiled file but the default settings still take precedence.

How can I force these settings to have the highest precedence?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account "specificity" of CSS, the #id generally takes precedence but it really depends on how the rules where declared in the first place. I'm not an expert of Foundation but you can read more about the subject on CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

A quick-and-dirty solution would be to use the `!important` flag on the properties, but I suggest you only do it as a last resort:

```css
#myid {
   background: blue !important;
   color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of how to do this in plain CSS, but in my situation it is not specific enough to override the Foundation settings. Thus I'm looking for a solution that may make use of Sass / Foundation aspect that would correctly override.

Comment: Your problem is about CSS specificity. Independently of the preprocessor/framework it's still CSS, so by inspecting the elements you can see how selectors are used and override them. If you need help with a concrete situation you might want to post some code.

Comment: I understand my problem is about CSS specificity, and I'm having a problem resolving it. I'm also aware that both Foundation/Sass have some standard style setup, but I'm not so familiar with it. PErhaps they have a standard way to address these issues using variables, mixins, or otherwise.

Comment: It might be worth investigating Foundation config variables to see if there is one that solves your issue. However, depending on your actual problem, you should inspect the elements (ex: with the Chrome console or Firefox/Firebug), and see the selectors used so that you can copy those and apply your changes.